# \raggedleft in conjunction with \\ not working in header

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, align, parbox

I am really struggling with the last change in my thesis regarding the header. The header is defined in the template I have to use like this:

```
\def\@evenhead{\parbox{\textwidth}{
     {\thepage\hfill~\slshape\leftmark} \\
      \rule[13pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}}}
```

When the chapter name is too long it will start a second line which is flushedleft since \parbox is a block sentence, so starts from the left. I would like to have it flushed right since this looks much nicer. However the problem is that \raggedleft is not working. I already found out that this is caused by the \ and the \rule. When I skip the rule it works just fine with \raggedleft, but I need the rule of course :/

Thank you already very much :)

Best regards
Christian

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The simplest (and best looking) would to use the optional argument of  `\chapter` to give a  short version of the chapter title.

Comment: Thank you, that is really a good idea, I have not thought about this yet :) and anyway one line looks much better as you say